# Get category for texts

Tags: php, comparison, similarity

I want to choose a category of text(article)(ex. sport,economic), string, and I want to know whether the best way to do with function `similar_text()` or otherwise. I need to compare the texts. One article is a description which should be assigned to categories. The second text is actually text with all the key words that describe the category. Comparing the two texts given the percentage of similarity. 
Text that has the most similarities with the particular category is in fact and that category. Should I do this cryptographic `similar_text()` or otherwise?

Comment: code example? really have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: ex. I need to write an algortam to automaticly get category for some text. example. is a text about sport. I need to get percentace of similarity. I compare this text about sport with other texts. Other texts is a key word which describe that category. When I compare all text category with my text about sport where I get biggest percentace of similarity that is the category for my text about sport and sport text will get sport category.

Comment: How to do that- Can I do this with similar_text() or not.

Comment: example is google news... google automaticly get category for text(atricle-news)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [Bayesian classifier](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-bayes3/) to determine the degree of similarity.